# Correct button size with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this form:

[image]

which is created by the following code:

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
  <div class="input-group add-on">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

How can I correct the button size? I want to be correctly aligned with the text box.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using only icon in button, add this css so it aligns with input box.

```
.glyphicon {
    top: 0px !important;
    line-height: inherit;
}
```